# How can I put a web word processor on my website?

Tags: syntax, web, syntax-highlighting, highlighting, word-processor

How would I implement a word processor on a website I'm making? The point is I want a user to be able to type in text and it have syntax highlighting in the text box they're typing in. Could someone instruct me in how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TinyMCE http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/
It's pretty easy to use it, look at the examples http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I hope I can remove all the unnecessary controls and get syntax highlighting working.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you have those:

- [YUI Editor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/)
- [Free Rich Text Editor](http://www.freerichtexteditor.com/)
- [RTE](http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/)

=D

Answer (score 0):

Actually I ended up using CodeMirror, it was perfect. Emacs also may be good for other people.